# intelliJ IDEA 13 CE "Comment with Line Comment" option is not available inside scripts

Tags: intellij-idea

Recently i started to work with this version of the IDEA (i worked with IDEA 9 until now)
for some reason the option to auto-comment inside script tags is not available, for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var a = 3; <- want to comment this using command + /
</script>
```

I've tried to go through Code->"Comment with Line Comment" but no good ( in IDEA 9 it worked )

does someone knows what can i do ?

thanks.

Comment: I just tried it with 13.1.3 (64-bit Win7) and it worked fine.

Comment: thanks, 
sorry forget to mention its 13.1.3 CE .
maybe because of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Community Edition (CE) has no builtin JavaScript support, so the language-specific "Comment Line" action is indeed not available.